# Is there a way to Implement conditional statements in Static Block

Tags: java, conditional-statements, hdfs, hbase, static-block

I have a class `HDFSHbaseInstance` which will load `Hbase` config in `static block`

```
public class HDFSHbaseInstance {
    private static FileSystem hadoopFS = null;
    private static Configuration config = null;
    static {
        try {
            config = HBaseConfiguration.create(new Configuration());
            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "10.21.1.111");
            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "1234");

            hadoopFS = FileSystem.get(config);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
// remaining code
}
```

Now for some reasons, I have to create one more class  `HDFSInstance` which will load `Hadoop` default config

```
public class HDFSInstance {
    private static FileSystem hadoopFS = null;
    private static Configuration config = null;
    static {
        try {
            config = new Configuration();
            hadoopFS = FileSystem.get(config);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
// remaining code which is same as upper class
}
```

Problem is here, I have a class which will decide to use anyone above class based on some condition. I am simply doing it through `conditional statement` like

```
public class A{
    main(){
        if (defaultConf) { HDFSInstance.callFun(); }
        if (hbaseConf) { HDFSHbaseInstance.callFun(); }
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to combine both `HDFSInstance` and `HDFSHbaseInstance` into one by adding `conditional statement` in `static block`?
2. I thought of `static constructor` but it wouldn't work in my present scenario, So Is there a  solution without creating `constructor`?

Comment: you can use `Factory design pattern`. Read about it https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factory-method-design-pattern-in-java/

Comment: It's a cool method. Factory design pattern requires objects needs to be created. since `HDFSHbaseInstance` has been used in so many places. I can't implement it. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That would be really bad design. At the very least move your static block to be a static method and in your checking flag invoke appropriate method. But really you should use a Factory pattern and fetch the appropriate class based on the value of your flag. I just answered similar question in detail. Please see my answer on this question: [How to us a custom ClassLoader to get different and new objects from a library in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036486/how-to-us-a-custom-classloader-to-get-different-and-new-objects-from-a-library-i/73037055#73037055)